# looping variables with same prefix

Tags: r, loops

I have a dataset having variables from Q1 to Q60. They are characters from 0 to 10. I want to convert them to numeric variables. I am a new user of R.

How can I do that in a loop?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Your question is not completely clear. Please follow the link below to learn how to ask a questions correctly
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) & [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) & Please include some data: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: `isQ <- grepl("^Q", colnames(x)); x[,isQ] <- lapply(x[,isQ], as.numeric)`

Comment: `library(tidyverse); df %>% gather(question, value) %>% mutate(value = as.numeric(value))`